# Colors change when converting GIF to VP9 WebM using FFmpeg

Tags: ffmpeg, colors, gif, webm, vp9

The colors come out fine when I try using `VP8 WebM` or `H264 MP4`, but whenever I use `VP9 WebM` there's a slight change in color. The change in color can be seen in `Chrome`, not sure about other browsers or viewers. I also tried [ezGIF online GIF to WebM converter](https://ezgif.com/gif-to-webm) (which uses `FFmpeg` under the hood), and it worked fine (colors remained the same), so I'm not sure why it's not working correctly when I run `FFmpeg` locally.

Command I used:

```
ffmpeg -i duck.gif duck.webm
```

Color difference screenshot:

[image: Duck Color Difference]

Orignal `GIF`:
[image: Original Duck GIF]

Output `WebM`:
https://sportyz.000webhostapp.com/duck.webm

Comment: Can you try doing the conversion with ffmpeg using [a custom palette](https://www.bannerbear.com/blog/how-to-make-a-gif-from-a-video-using-ffmpeg/#enhancement)? I don't know if that plays a role in conversion to `webm`, but maybe worth a try. [Possible helpful scripts](https://gist.github.com/goncalossilva/865e90b66e4bddc58f40).

Comment: Using a palette seems to work, however it removes alpha/transparency so now the video has a white/black/yellow background (depending on my exact command). Here's what I tried:  `ffmpeg -i duck.gif -filter_complex palettegen=use_alpha=1" palette.png`. and then: `ffmpeg -i duck.gif -i palette.png -filter_complex paletteuse=use_alpha=1 duck.webm`

Comment: The issue is related to transparency. When I open the WebM in Chrome browser, the video background is black. How did you get the vp9 to play on white background?

Comment: The original WebM I created has no background(it's transparent). If you add it to a HTML page with a white background, its background will be white. If you just open it in its own tab in chrome, chrome will automatically show a page with a black background. However, you can change that as well by right clicking on the page, choosing inspect, clicking on the body element and adding "background-color: white" to element.style.

Comment: Here I created a small webpage to illustrate the problem more clearly: https://sportyz.000webhostapp.com/duck.html

Comment: Try the following command: `ffmpeg -y -i duck.gif -vf scale=out_color_matrix=bt709:out_range=tv -pix_fmt yuva420p duck2.webm` when using  `out_color_matrix=bt709:out_range=tv` the color looks the same to me as the animated gif. Please check if the colors are the same.

Answer (score 2):

Adding `-vf scale=out_color_matrix=bt709:out_range=tv` to FFmpeg command seems to solve the issue.
"Just in case", we may also mark the stream Metadata as BT.709 and "TV Range":

`ffmpeg -y -i duck.gif -vf scale=out_color_matrix=bt709:out_range=tv -pix_fmt yuva420p -bsf:v vp9_metadata=color_space=bt709:color_range=tv duck2.webm`

---

For non-HDR video there are two mainly used color standards: [BT.601](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rec._601) and [BT.709](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rec._709).
The difference is the conversion matrix from RGB to YUV color space.

There are also two main color ranges for YUV: "TV Range" applies values in range [16, 235], and "PC Range" applies values in range [0, 255].

It looks like FFmpeg uses BT.601 conversion by default (when encoding VP9), while Chrome assumes BT.709 standard (when decoding VP9).
The result is a noticeable "color shift".

---

For overcoming the issue, we may select "BT.709" and "TV Range" **explicitly**.

- `scale=out_color_matrix=bt709:out_range=tv` - enforces conversion from RGB to YUV using BT.709 conversion formula, and "TV Range" range.
- `-bsf:v vp9_metadata=color_space=bt709:color_range=tv` sets the stream Metadata to BT.709 and "TV Range" (probably not required).

---

HTML code used for testing:

```html
<body style="background-color:cornflowerblue">
    <img src="duck.gif">
    <div>Original GIF</div>
    <br><br><br>
    <video autoplay loop muted playsinline src="duck2.webm"></video> <div>WebM conversion with bt709 and TV range</div>
    <br><br><br>
</body>
```

---

Output in Chrome browser:
[image]

Comment: It's super close. looks about 95% the same, but still ever so slightly different. The difference is more noticeable if you put the 2 images in 2 different tabs and switch between them, especially if you zoom in the page to say 200%. The conversion using a palette on the other hand is 100% perfect (except the white background issue). If there is no way to get a palette conversion working together with transparency I will use your solution, as most people will never notice the difference anyway. Thanks for the help and time you put into this.